# why does the following code prints a byte as an integer?

Tags: java

Shouldn't address.getAddress())[2]) be printing in 0-1 or byte format because it itself is a byte. Why is it printing -126?

```
public static void main(String s[]) {
    try {
        String arg="www.google.com";
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(arg);
        System.out.println("Address: " + (address.getAddress())[2]));
    } catch (UnknownHostException exc) {
        System.out.println(exc);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's printed in decimal form.

Comment: Java bytes are signed.

Comment: It's the defined behavior.

Comment: What is "0-1" format?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, a `byte` is an 8-bit *signed* integer. This means that it can take values from decimal -128 to decimal +127.

When you say *byte format*, you might mean an unsigned value from 0 to 255. If you want to use a `byte b` as an unsigned value, you should use `b & 0xff`.

If what you're trying to do is print the byte as a two-character hex string, you should use

```
String.format("%02X", b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of bytes in Java are from -128 to 127. -126 is a valid byte value.